# Making number transitions smooth

Tags: lua

I have a variable that, when function is called, gets multiplied by 1.01. What I want is, instead of just seeing that variable "jump" to another value, to see it smoothly and gradually increase until it reaches that value.

Example:

```
    x = 1000
    function gets called
    x = x * 1.01 
--> x value is now 1010, but when I show it on screen, I would like it to go 1000, 1001, 1002,...,1010 in certain amount of time
--> instead of just 1000 -> 1010
```

My code so far:

```
function Multiply()
                local random = math.random(1, 102)
                    if random ~= 1 then
                        Multiplier = Multiplier * 1.01
                        MultiplierDisplay.text = "x" .. string.format("%.3f", Multiplier)

                        Gain = Multiplier * PlaceYourBetTextField.text - PlaceYourBetTextField.text
                        GainDisplay.text = "Gain: " .. string.format("%.0f", Gain)
                    else
                        timer.cancel(MultiplyTimer)
                        Multiplier = 1
                    end
                end
                MultiplyTimer = timer.performWithDelay(125, Multiply, 0)
```

Comment: So... what problems are you having with doing that?

Comment: EDIT: I rephrased my question, I asked it wrong, sorry for that.

I have no idea how to perform that... When my function multiplies large numbers, it simply jumps from 10000 to 10100. I want to to go 1 by 1. It's kind of hard to explain... Hopefully someone can tho.

Comment: I understand your problem perfectly. My question was what have you done to attempt to solve it? Clearly, you wouldn't think that the number would magically take on the intermediate values, so obviously you will need to write some code to make it do that. What code did you attempt to write to accomplish that? What algorithms did you try?

Comment: I tried using transition.to, but that doesn't work, obviously. I tried also changing delay on timer to like 50 ms, but that it just too fast for my needs. I will edit my post so you can check my function.

Comment: A for loop should be a rather simple, yet very effect, solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to choose how much time to make this transition over.
I'm assuming that because you're multiplying stuff, that you'll want a constant geometric change instead of a constant arithmetic change.

You would do

```
local x=1000

local x0=0
local x1=0
local time0=0
local time1=0

local function changex(newx,time)
    x0=x
    x1=newx
    time0=os.clock()
    time1=time0+time
end
```

and then your main loop:

```
while true do
    local t=os.clock()
    if t<time0 then
        x=x0
    elseif t<time1 then
        local tratio=(t-time0)/(time1-time0)
        x=x0*(x1/x0)^tratio
    else
        x=x1
    end
    pause()
end
```